# Issues connecting to my Wordpress MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am currently trying to create a new database in my Wordpress MySQl database to store information. I am running into issues connecting with the database and extracting the data to be displayed on a page. I imported some data into the database through phpMyAdmin. My php to connect to the Wordpress database was:

```
$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
```

For the appropriate username and password I went into my wp-config.php file. I was having ussues finding the servername for the connection. When I used the Server Hostname found in  my cPannel it would print connected successfully on my localhost server but I wasn't able to extract the data.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: please show the **complete** error message

Comment: I apologize here it is: Connection failed: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: You should log into the database and check he grants for that user.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error when the user ***username*** does not have the right access to your MySQL database. To resolve the error, you should grant permissions to the user with the following command in MySQL command-line client or phpMyAdmin:

```
GRANT all privileges ON dbname.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

but it's not recommended to give a non-root user all privileges, you can create new user and grants custom privileges like this:

```
GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON dbname.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```